# MariaDB using 'distinct' keyword changes expected behavior of other column

Tags: sql, mariadb

Why does this work:

```sql
SET @cnt = 0;
SELECT (@cnt:=@cnt+1) AS 'foo', title FROM employee;
```

[image]

But when I add 'distinct' keyword, it does not, while distinct works on its own (not shown).

```sql
SET @cnt = 0;
SELECT (@cnt:=@cnt+1) AS 'foo', distinct title FROM employee; // "error in syntax"
```

In other words, you can have a custom column or a distinct keyword but not both.

I think it's because each part is trying to return a different number of records for each and that throws an error, but I want it to return the same number of records, the distinct column being the limiter. Please share the keywords and technical terms of what I'm trying to do so I can learn and grow. Also let me know if this should've/could've gone in the database admin stack exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This syntax is nonsensical SQL:

```
SELECT (@cnt:=@cnt+1) AS 'foo', distinct title
FROM employee; // "error in syntax"
```

Why?  Because `DISTINCT` is used in two places in SQL (that I can readily think of):

- As a modifier to aggregation functions, notably `COUNT(DISTINCT)`.
- As part of the SQL keyword `SELECT DISTINCT`.

(There are other uses such as `IS DISTINCT FROM` but MySQL does not support that.)

In the latter case, the `DISTINCT` applies to *all* columns being selected.  I would recommend putting this in a subquery:

```
SELECT (@cnt := @cnt + 1) AS foo, title
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT title FROM employee) e; // "error in syntax"
```

Comment: I knew the answer was probably simple- just select and append to the results from a subquery. This is great.